# On the legality of booby traps in a far future united states

Tags: united-states, us-federal-government, self-defense, law-in-fiction

So there are a few famous cases in the united states wherein booby traps were ruled to be illegal, as they're indiscriminate in their application.

Let's say we have material X. Material X is special, in that if someone applies harm with intent to hurt a human, and that harm is detected by Material X, it will instantly cause serious bodily harm towards the aggressor. Material X knows the intentions of the person, and will apply said harm accordingly. It is **never** wrong. Police and Firefighters acting with the intent to help people will never be hurt by Material X nor will innocent children, individuals, or animals. Material X **only** harms "bad guys".

To my understanding, material x is very discriminatory, and thus would be legal to booby trap my property with, no? For the sake of the question, we can assume we're in the state most lenient towards booby traps with regard to legislation, and that federal law is the focus here.

Is my understanding correct?

Comment: This looks like a question for work building SE…

Comment: And how would the designers of Material X implement the axiom "One person's terrorist is another person's freedom fighter"?

Comment: I don't understand the point of these questions. OP has laid out a hypothetical scenario and asked how the law applies to it. World Building has nothing to offer on this question.

Comment: @bdb484 Because the scenario that the OP is suggesting is so fantastical that it will never occur in the real world.  It's like asking what is the role of customs and immigration laws in a world where everyone can fly like Superman.   It's purely philosophical rumination.

Comment: Speaking in very broad terms, in the US it is generally illegal to intentionally cause harm to others.

Comment: @Rick to my knowledge material x does not exist in any form as it stands today.

Comment: Vladimir Mandl in 1932: ["What would current laws say about human-occupied space stations?"](http://bit.ly/3P7aNsd) Law.SE: "Downvote! The scenario you're suggesting is so fantastical that it will never occur in the real world. Take your stupid imagination and keep it to yourself."

Comment: @bdb484 Discussing outer space law in the 1930's was reasonable, because even though no one had  achieved space flight at that time, it was not precluded by the laws of physics known at even only that time.  OTOH there are no laws of physics, known, or even speculated on that enables a device to telepathically make a determination of intent.

Comment: A legal system anything like our own has no relevance to a world where objects can infallibly know a person's intent.

Comment: What Ohwilleke said. If human intentions could be known in advance our entire society would look very different than it does today and current systems of law would need a major overhaul. (*Asking how ancient Roman law addresses software copyrights would probably be more relevant*). Would/could such a thing as a booby trap even exist? Hence my world building comment… (I didn’t vote to close FWIW)

Comment: imagine closing a question on law.se as opinion based. that's when you know that they dont really have a good reason

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[canada](/questions/tagged/canada)

#### It would be *prima facie* setting a trap or causing bodily harm with a trap

The act of deploying Material X would be the offence of setting a trap likely to cause bodily harm. If Material X is triggered then it would also be the offence of causing bodily harm with a trap. See s. [247](https://laws-lois.justice.gc.ca/eng/acts/C-46/section-247.html) *Criminal Code*.

#### Self defence or defence of another require that the illegal act be *reasonable in the circumstances*

For self-defence or defence-of-another to excuse or justify this act, one needs to satisfy the elements of s. 34 of the *Criminal Code*:

> 34 (1) A person is not guilty of an offence if
>
> (a) they believe on reasonable grounds that force is being used against them or another person or that a threat of force is being made against them or another person;
>
> (b) the act that constitutes the offence is committed for the purpose of defending or protecting themselves or the other person from that use or threat of force; and
>
> (c) **the act committed is reasonable in the circumstances**.
>
> (2) **In determining whether the act committed is reasonable in the
> circumstances, the court shall consider the relevant circumstances of
> the person, the other parties and the act, including, but not limited
> to, the following factor**s:
>
> (a) the nature of the force or threat;
>
> (b) the extent to which the use of force was imminent and whether
> there were other means available to respond to the potential use of
> force;
>
> (c) the person’s role in the incident;
>
> (d) whether any party to the incident used or threatened to use a
> weapon;
>
> (e) the size, age, gender and physical capabilities of the parties to
> the incident;
>
> (f) the nature, duration and history of any relationship between the
> parties to the incident, including any prior use or threat of force
> and the nature of that force or threat;
>
> (f.1) any history of interaction or communication between the parties
> to the incident;
>
> (g) the nature and proportionality of the person’s response to the use
> or threat of force; and
>
> (h) whether the act committed was in response to a use or threat of
> force that the person knew was lawful.

The Supreme Court has said (*R. v. Khill*, 2021 SCC 37):

> it is for the trier of fact to assess and weigh the factors and determine whether or not the act was reasonable. This is a global, holistic exercise. No single factor is necessarily determinative of the outcome.

#### The use of Material X would not be reasonable in many circumstances

The fact that Material X will "instantly cause **serious bodily harm** towards the aggressor", triggered by *any* harm with intent, would in many circumstances take the use of Material X outside of what would be found to be a reasonable act in self-defence or defence of another.

Comment: I tagged this as united states, but this canadian law perspective is very interesting, and provides some relevant insight, I think.,

Comment: You missed that what is reasonable of the circumstances requires knowledge of the actual circumstances - it’s impossible to know them in advance.